# Codeigniter AutoLoad DB, But have ability to check if connection exists

Tags: php, codeigniter

How would I autoload the database using autoload.php

I already got the autoloading of course... that's the easy part.

But also allowing me to check if the db has been connected to, and if not, to display a specific page saying something like "We are sorry but our database is currently unavailable."

Would it have to be some kind of custom hook that I would have to make?

Comment: if it is not able to connect to the database it would throw error and wont continue. You somehow need to override that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the error template in `application/errors/error_db.php` to use your custom message. Maybe use the `ENVIRONMENT` constant and do something like this:

```
<?php if (ENVIRONMENT === 'production'): ?>
  <p>We are sorry but our database is currently unavailable.</p>
<?php else: ?>
  <!-- default template with actual database error messages -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Otherwise, I suppose you could use a hook. It would have to be at least `pre_controller` if you are auto loading the database class and want to intercept the error, or you could just load the database class in the `__construct()` of a `MY_Controller` class after doing your connection check. You could even just do it right in the first line of `index.php` if you wanted to.

However: I think what you're looking for might be in the language files. Take a look at:
 `system/language/english/db_lang.php`.
If you create your own file in the same place, but in `/application` instead of `/system`, you can just rewrite the appropriate language line(s):

```
// $lang['db_unable_to_connect'] = 'Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.';
$lang['db_unable_to_connect'] = 'We are sorry but our database is currently unavailable.';
```

...and just edit the CSS and/or markup in the error template. Once again, you can take advantage of the `ENVIRONMENT` constant to show useful errors in development mode, and show user-friendly ones in production.

Of course, if you can't connect to your database - that's a major problem that needs immediate attention.

Comment: Not doing it because of it not connecting at some points, I'm only doing it so I can learn (The site I'm making isn't going to be public)