# CodeIgniter connection db custom error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i have this code

```
    $specific['hostname'] = "localhost";
    $specific['username'] = "root";
    $specific['password'] = "";
    $specific['database'] = "ci_forsyria";
    $specific['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $specific['dbprefix'] = "";
    $specific['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $specific['db_debug'] = FALSE;
    $specific['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $specific['cachedir'] = "";
    $specific['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $specific['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

$specific_db = $this->load->database($specific, TRUE);
```

i use this parameter "FALSE" to hide connection error !

```
$specific['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

but how i can create custom error message if connection field

like

$connect = $this->db->connect;
    if(!$connect)
    {
        // print error message ..
    }

Comment: possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167835/codeigniter-autoload-db-but-have-ability-to-check-if-connection-exists

Comment: i must to stop error because i want my page load in both

Comment: $specific['db_debug'] = FALSE;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB_Debug is designed to show Database error messages.

You have turned that functionality off with "$specific['db_debug'] = FALSE;"

So instead you need to turn it back on, and filter the $error message on the error_db.php file.

i.e. inside error_db.php

```
 <? php if ($message === 'Database connection error')
         {
               echo $message;
         }
         else
         {
               echo "error - sorry";
         } ?>
```

or something like that